# How to return the following _.map + Promise function?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I have two functions, one that finds Parse objects and another that uses that find function and loops through the objects:

**store.js:**

```
const store = {}
const Document = Parse.Object.extend('Document')

store.find = () => {
  const query = new Parse.Query(Document)
  return query.find()
}

store.fetch = () => {
  return store.find().then((results) => {
    _.map(results, (result) => {
      return result.toJSON()
    })
  })
}
```

Now I'm just doing `console.log()` to log the output:

**main.js**

```
console.log(store.fetch())
```

But the `console.log` logs this:

> ParsePromise {_resolved: false, _rejected: false, _resolvedCallbacks:
>   Array[0], _rejectedCallbacks: Array[0]}

How to modify the code to get the actual array of objects?

Comment: Do you get the results if you do `console.log(results)` inside of your then?

Comment: @JeremyJackson No, `console.log(results)` returns `[ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your `fetch` function has to return the result of `_.map` like this

   ```
   store.fetch = () => {
     return store.find().then((results) => {
       return _.map(results, (result) => {
         return result.toJSON()
       })
     })
   }
   ```

   so that the then handlers attached to `store.fetch` will get the array object returned by `_.map`
2. `store.fetch()` will be returning a Promise object and that will be resolved asynchronously. So you need to attach a `then` handler to it and print the result, like this

   ```
   store.fetch().then((result) => console.log(result));
   ```

Comment: Thanks! One question: is there a way to modify 1. so that there aren't so many `returns`?

Comment: @alexchenco Hmmm, the code looks okay to me as it is.

Comment: I see, thanks. I was thinking that I could return `[Object, Object, Object ...` with `store.fetch`. That way I can just do `this.documents = store.fetch()` in `main.js`.

Comment: @alexchenco Hmmm, that wouldn't have worked because the `fetch` is an asynchronous function returning a Promise :-)

Comment: @thfourtheye I see. So there's no way of doing what I suggested in the comment?

Comment: @alexchenco Nope. Because when the `store.fetch()` function call gets over, the request to find will be submitted to the DB. When the DB responds, the Promise will be resolved and the `then` handler will be invoked (if there are no errors)

Comment: By the way, I figured out how to remove the three returns:

`store.find = () => {
  const query = new Parse.Query(Document)
  return query.find().then((results) =>
    _.map(results, (result) =>
      result.toJSON()
    )
  )
}`

I think removing the curly brackets makes the lines stop acting as a block, hence removing the need of a `return` in each of them?